# Origin of Term in Proof of Gauss's Digamma Theorem Cast as the $p/q$th Harmonic Number?

Tags: solution-verification, generating-functions

I'm working through exercise 19 in section 1.2.9 of Knuth's *The Art of Computer Programming* volume 1, which asks, using the definition

$$
   H_{p/q} = \sum_{n \geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+p/q}\right)\text{,}
$$

to prove that

$$
   H_{p/q} = \frac{q}{p} - \frac{\pi}{2}\cot\frac{p}{q}\pi - \ln 2q + 2\sum_{0 < k < q/2}\cos\frac{2pk}{q}\pi \cdot \ln\sin\frac{k}{q}\pi\text{,}
$$

when $p$ and $q$ are integers with $0  < p < q$. The desired solution starts by using Abel's limit theorem to find

$$
\begin{aligned}
   H_{p/q} &= \sum_{n \geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+p/q}\right)\\
           &= \lim_{x \to 1-}\sum_{n \geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n + p/q}\right)x^{p+nq} & \text{(1)}\\
           &= \lim_{x \to 1-}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{q-1}\omega^{-kp}\ln(1-\omega^k x) - x^p\ln(1-x^q) + \frac{q}{p}x^p\right)\text{,} & \text{(2)}\\
\end{aligned}
$$

where $\omega = e^{2\pi i/q}$.

I'm having trouble getting completely from (1) to (2). I'm able to derive the first two terms of (2), but am unsure of the origin of the $\frac{q}{p}x^p$ term.

So far I have, in the limit as $x \to 1-$,

$$
\begin{aligned}
   &\sum_{n \geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n + p/q}\right)x^{p+nq}\\
   &\quad= -\sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{1}{n + p/q}x^{p+nq} + \sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{1}{n}x^{p+nq}\\
   &\quad= -\sum_{\substack{n > 0\\p + nq \bmod q = p}}\frac{q}{p + nq}x^{p+nq} + \sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{1}{n}x^{p+nq}\\
   &\quad= -\frac{1}{q}\sum_{0 \leq k < q}\omega^{-kp}\sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{q}{n}\omega^{kn}x^{n} + \sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{1}{n}x^{p+nq} & \text{by Eq. (13)}\\
   &\quad= \sum_{0 \leq k < q}\omega^{-kp}\sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}(-\omega^{k}x)^{n} + \sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{1}{n}x^{p+nq}\\
   &\quad= \sum_{0 \leq k < q}\omega^{-kp}\ln(1 - \omega^{k}x) + \sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{1}{n}x^{p+nq} & \text{by Eq. (24)}\\
   &\quad= \sum_{0 \leq k < q}\omega^{-kp}\ln(1 - \omega^{k}x) - x^{p}\sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}(-x^q)^{n}\\
   &\quad= \sum_{0 \leq k < q}\omega^{-kp}\ln(1 - \omega^{k}x) - x^{p}\ln(1 - x^q) & \text{by Eq. (24)}\text{.}\\
\end{aligned}
$$

Where is the $\frac{q}{p}x^{p}$ term supposed to come from?

Equations referenced include

$$
   \sum_{\substack{n > 0\\n \bmod m = r}}a_{n}z^{n} = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{0 \leq k < m}\omega^{-kr}G(\omega^{k}z)\text{,}\quad\text{$0 \leq r < m$,} \tag{13}
$$

with $\omega = e^{2\pi i/m}$ and $G(z)$ the generating function for $\langle a_n \rangle$; and

$$
   \ln(1 + z) = \sum_{k \geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}z^{k}\text{.} \tag{24}
$$

I've also looked through errata to see if this was an error in the printing I have—the twenty-fifth of the third edition—but to no avail. Thanks for any insight!

Comment: [This might help](https://planetmath.org/proofofgaussdigammatheorem).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, Mark. It turns out I was missing a term from the application of Eq. (13), which apparently is *not* for $n > 0$ but for $n \geq 0$. That is,

$$
\begin{aligned}
   &-\sum_{\substack{n > 0\\p+nq \bmod q = p}}\frac{q}{p+nq}x^{p+nq}\\
   &\quad= \frac{q}{p}x^{p} - \sum_{\substack{n \geq 0\\p+nq \bmod q = p}}\frac{q}{p+nq}x^{p+nq}\\
   &\quad= \frac{q}{p}x^{p} - \frac{1}{q}\sum_{0 \leq k < q}\omega^{-kp}\sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{q}{n}\omega^{kn}x^{n}\text{,} & \quad \text{by Eq. (13)}\\
\end{aligned}
$$

meaning the referenced equation should really read

$$
   \sum_{\substack{n \geq 0\\n \bmod m = r}}a_{n}z^{n} = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{0 \leq k < m}\omega^{-kr}G(\omega^{k}z)\text{,}\quad\text{$0 \leq r < m$.} \tag{13}
$$

(Note that this is a known [erratum](https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/%7Eknuth/all1-pre.ps.gz) in the twenty-fifth printing.)